# Find out if ASP.NET radio button is checked without knowing the Id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Forms page and there is a `fieldset` and inside this there are items that each have a radio button. Basically I want to determine if a certain item is checked. However, it appears that it's location could move and therefore the `id` could change if the database is updated. How can I determine if the item is checked using if the `id` attribute can change? I don't think the value would change, how can I determine if it is checked by using the `value` attribute?

I would like to add a class as suggested but I really only want to use javascript and not change any of the ASP.NET code in the .aspx file.

```
<fieldset style="padding-left: 5px;">
  <input id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder_rblstRole_8" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ContentPlaceHolder$rblstRole" value="36">
  <label for="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder_rblstRole_8">Agency VP</label>
  <br>
  <input id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder_rblstRole_9" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ContentPlaceHolder$rblstRole" value="13">
  <label for="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ContentPlaceHolder_rblstRole_9">Agent</label>
...
```

Comment: You should use the ClientId (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. <%: rblstRole.ClientId%> or similar.

Comment: An alternative to what EBrown said, you can change the radio button's `ClientIDMode` to static so that the ID won't change even if the location moves.

Comment: add a class so ID becomes irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attribute selector of jQuery:

```
$('input[value="36"]').is(':checked')
```

and you can see the working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/5637csyz/

Comment: `$('input:radio[value="36"]').is(':checked')` type filter would be more help full.